# Rails form helpers not working in only one of my controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having this weird issue where trying to render a form using form helpers gives me the following error: `NoMethodError in Admin#login undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`, the weird thin, I'm only getting this error in my `Admin` controller and not ain any of the other ones.

I tried pasting the form into a view associated with a different controller and it rendered fine. I also tried pasting a working form from a different page into this one and it gave me the same error.

Here's my controller:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController    
    def login        
    end

    def session
    end
end
```

Here's my `login.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_with url: login_path do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :title %>
<% end %>
```

And here's the relevant output from running `rake routes`:

```
          root GET   /                                  website#index
         admin GET   /admin(.:format)                   admin#admin
         login GET   /login(.:format)                   admin#login
               POST  /login(.:format)                   admin#session
```

This form works with any other controller, just not with the `AdminController` and other forms that work on other pages don't work in this one. I get the same error using `form_tag` and `form_for`.

Rails Version 5.1.4

Ruby Version 2.3.2

Here's the stack trace I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
from /home/yechielk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:374:in `real_csrf_token'
from /home/yechielk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:381:in `per_form_csrf_token'
from /home/yechielk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:302:in `masked_authenticity_token'
from /home/yechielk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:291:in `form_authenticity_token'
from /home/yechielk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:68:in `form_authenticity_token'
from /home/yechielk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:598:in `token_tag'
from /home/yechielk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:855:in `extra_tags_for_form'
from /home/yechielk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:875:in `form_tag_html'
from /home/yechielk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:765:in `form_with'
from /home/yechielk/Desktop/code/Personal/personal-site/app/views/admin/login.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_admin_login_html_erb___3018772792552054965_27358140'
```

Comment: So, are you getting that error when rendering the form or when submitting it?

Comment: When rendering it.

Comment: could you please list all the rails routes?

Comment: @Leo added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

Turns out when I defined a controller action called `session` it overwrote the `session` variable (to `nil` in this case) which broke a different librry that was calling `session`.

Comment: Well, your question didn't have enough information for anyone to be able to help you in that case since there was no `session` action in the original `admin` controller you posted.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. It's always the parts you don't think are relevant that end up messing with you... :(